# How to use the insert method correctly for Python

Tags: python, insert

I'm having trouble with this question:

Write a function insert_item_end(data, item) that takes a list data, and item as a parameter and returns a new list that contains item at the end of the data using the insert method (i.e. you cannot use append).

This is what I've done so far:

```
data.insert(-1, item)
```

However, this only returns None.

Here is an example of what I want to return:

([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1) returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]

Comment: `list.insert` **always** returns `None`. But it modifies the `list` object in-place. Note also, it inserts *before* the index, so `data.insert(-1, 1)` would give you `[1,2,3,4,1,5]`

Comment: So, your instructions say you need to create a new list. You *could* use `.insert` (although, inserting at the *end* is just `.append`) to do this, but you would have to copy the incoming list first. Then modify that list, and return it. There is probably a cleaner way to do that than explicitly copying...

Comment: To be painfully honest; this is a *ridiculous* exercise as it 1) uses `insert` in a way in which it was not designed (i.e. the reason we have `append`) and 2) forces the student to write verbose code, which is neither efficient nor Pythonic.  Suggestion: Find a new course.  Quick!

Comment: ...or; perhaps stick with the course and when you see a problem that seems counter intuitive, challenge it.  As you as doing here.  There is usually a very simple solution when it comes to Python.

Answer (score 1):

Do this suit your requirement?

```
def insert_item_end(data,item):
    newlist=[];
    newlist=data
    newlist.insert(len(data),item)
    print(newlist)


data=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
item=1

insert_item_end(data, item)
```

Comment: You can eliminate the first line of the function, as you're anyways redefining `newlist` on the second.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
data.insert(len(data),item)
```

technically -1 and len(data)-1 should also work but i don't know why its inserting at the second last position.

Comment: @Aryman_Deshwal - The reason `data.insert(len(data) - 1, item)` inserts the item into the second to last position is because the length of a list, as returned by `len` is always going to be 1 greater than the last index of the list. So if there are three items in the list, and you want to add an item to the end of the list, you'll want to add an item to `data[3]`, because a list's index starts being counted at 0, so right now there are elements at `data[0]`, `data[1]`, and `data[2]`. The fourth element you add will be `data[3]`.

Comment: Now, `len(data)` returns `3`, which is one greater than the last index of the list: 2. So if you subtract one from this, you'd be adding item to `data[2]`, and whatever was already at `data[2]` gets pushed to `data[3]`. That's why `item` ends up in the second to last position.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify @Priyankarao's function by simply modifying the list that's passed to your function, instead of defining a new one. Something like this:

```
def append_to_list(data,item):
    data.insert(len(data),item)
    return data
```

Then run it like so:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
item = 6

newlist = append_to_list(nums, item)
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```